# How it works in C? (implement strcat function)

Tags: c, linux, while-loop

how it works in line 5~7?

```
while(*dst++){
}

dst--;
```

here is my code

```
void strcat_p(char *dest, char *src)

{

     while (*dest++) {
     }
     dest--;

     while(*src) {

         *dest++ = *src++;

   }

     *dst = *src
}

int main()
{

     char str1[20];

     strcat_p(str1, ", world!");

}
```

Comment: What part of it don't you understand? How `while` works? What `++` does? What `*dst` is?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you be a bit more precise what you are unsure about?

Comment: It is looking for the string's NUL terminator. When it finds it, it has already incremented past, so `dest--;` afterwards.

Comment: `char str1[20];` is uninitialized, so appending something to it would be undefined behavior. Maybe you want something like `char str1[20] = "Hello";`

Comment: @Bodo If `*dest` is 0, `dest++` will be executed nevertheless making `dest` point behind the terminating 0.

Comment: @4386427 No, his comment is correct... the contents of the local array holds indeterminate values.

Comment: A bit off-topic, the least naive manual version of strcat seems to be this: https://godbolt.org/z/weBzF-. I don't think you can optimize that code further, short of making an alignment-based version for a specific compiler port.

Comment: @Lundin well, it was another (now deleted comment) that was wrong. :-) Anyway, as the wrong comment has been deleted, I can delete mine as well.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the code is to make `dest` point just after the last character of the destination string so that the characters from the source string can be added from that point and forward.

The bad thing about `while(*dest++)` is that it **always** increments `dest`, i.e. even when `*dest` is NUL (`'\0'`), `dest` will be incremented. So, in order to "get back" to the NUL, a decrement of `dest` is needed after the loop.

The code:

```
while(*dest++){
}
dest--;
```

is equivalent to:

```
while(1){
    char tmp = *dest;        // Save current value in tmp
    dest++;                  // Increment dest
    if (tmp == '\0') break;  // Check tmp and stop the loop if it's NUL
}

dest--;                       // Compensate for the unwanted increment
```

The code should just have been:

```
while(*dest) dest++;
```

In that way the increment is only done when needed (so there is no longer a need for the decrement)

OT:

Make sure to initialize `str1` to something - at least do:

```
char str1[20] = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

This loop runs as long as the destination pointer points to a character. The loop should have been written as

```
    while (*dest != '\0') {
        dest++;
    }
```

It will produce exactly the same result but is much more readable.

After the loop the destination pointer points to the `'\0'` as the end-of-string character.

Answer (score 1):

The loop

```
while(*dst++)
   { /*empty loop body */ }
```

executes until `dst` points to a null character. *But it always increments `dst` so after the loop `dst` points beyond the null character and therefore a `dst--;` must be done.*

`*dst++` means to evaluate if `*dst` is a null character, then increment the pointer and if it was a null character, exit the loop. Users *the busybee*'s answer shows a better way of writing the loop.

Comment: I want to know why dst--; must be done?

Comment: Nokh, I made the relevant part of my answer italic: dst goes one too far.

Comment: @nokh9503 Because the code is badly written. It should have been `while(*dst != '\0') dst++;` and then the ugly `dst--` isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

The first `while` loop runs until `'\0` character is found, so that we know where terminating character of `*dest` is. That means we found the point where to append the `*src` string.

Then, by running second `while` loop, we simply append each value of `*src` to `*dest` until `*src` is a valid reference, or in other words, until `*src` character value reaches `'\0`.

Basically I think you have to learn how to use pointers, which is a **key topic** in C programming. I'd suggest you to do that before going on in studying C.

By the way, I understand you are new here, let me give you advice: try to be clearer in posting your question next time, so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

For starters this array

```
 char str1[20];
```

is not initialized and does not contain a string. So the call of the function

```
strcat_p(str1, ", world!");
```

results in undefined behavior.

The function is also declared incorrectly. It should be declared like

```
char * strcat_p( char *dest, const char *src );
```

The implementation of the function is confusing.

It can be defined the following way

```
char * strcat_p( char *dest, const char *src )
{
    char *p = dest;

    while( *p != '\0' ) ++p;

    do
    {
        *p++ = *src;
    } while ( *src++ != '\0' );

    return dest;
}
```

In the first loop

```
while( *p != '\0' ) ++p;
```

we are searching the end of the destination string because we are going to append the source string to the end of the destination string. And strings are defined as sequences of characters ended with the terminating zero character '\0'.

In this loop

```
    do
    {
        *p++ = *src;
    } while ( *src++ != '\0' );
```

We are doing the appending.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * strcat_p( char *dest, const char *src )
{
    char *p = dest;

    while( *p != '\0' ) ++p;

    do
    {
        *p++ = *src;
    } while ( *src++ != '\0' );

    return dest;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char str1[20] = "Hello";

    puts( strcat_p( str1, ", world!" ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello, world!
```

Answer (score -1):

@The busybee answered your question correctly.

Note that this code could have been expressed even clearlier with an extra variable using this code.

```cpp
int i=0;
while(dest[i] != '\0') {
    i++;
}
i--;
```

The "number of character optimisations" made in the original code are:

```
*i <=> i[0]
'\0' <=> 0
*x is applied before x++ in *x++
```

Comment: Nothing more clear, possibly incompatible with the remainder of the code and les efficient as it requires indexing.